# Simple rating Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rating

Does anyone know any good and compatible with RoR 3 plugin for rating?

I prefer thumbs up, thumbs down but star rating is fine as well.

I know that ajaxful_rating has a Rails 3 branch but I would like to hear your opinion if you have found something better with thumbs.

Thanks

**Edit:**

Found an example:

```
<img class="rate up" src="thumns_up.png" alt="Rate Up" />
<img class="rate down" src="thumns_down.png" alt="Rate Down" />


$(document).ready(function() {
 $("img.rate").click(function () {
       var val = ($(this).hasClass("up") == true) ? "1" : "-1";
       $.ajax(
             // Where should I pass the val?? 
       );
 });
});
```

Comment: just as a reference, railscast have some examples on how to implement it yourself. http://goo.gl/L2Ue5

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a 0-3 star rating for my site.  I'm not using any RoR gems/plugins to do it (I just created a Rating model with user_id, rater_id, and score).  Then I used this jQuery plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Star_Rating_widget) to display the actual star ratings.  It works great and is very customizable.

Comment: It seems really good but you have to write all validations yourself right? for example only one vote per user etc..

Comment: I really only have three validations.  validates_presence_of (all the attributes), validates_inclusion_of :score (to ensure the score is valid), and validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :rater_id (to handle one vote per user).  With comments my class is only ~30 lines.

Answer (score 0):

This could be handy:

http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/building-a-star-rating-system-in-ruby-on-rails-with-jquery/

Comment: doesn't it answer your needs?

Answer (score 0):

What about RatyRate? It's a quick solution with gem for 5 star ratings.

Here's an good explanation about it: http://www.sitepoint.com/ratyrate-add-rating-rails-app/

Answer (score 0):

Here you have rating tools:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_ratings

I recomend you https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate